# How to determine if my database is auditing logins, and if not how do I set that up?

Tags: oracle

I run Oracle 19C but with traditional auditing rather than unified auditing due to historical reasons.
I'm trying to determine why my DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL content does not currently show correct logins, but only failed login attempts.

I am interested in tracking successful logins and logoffs as complementary work to an infrastructure I am building to use proxy authentication.

Without DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL giving me login information, the proxy_sessionid for the client when I use proxy_authentication does not return anything when I search in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL, which makes tracking the login of who initiated the proxy very difficult.

Comment: perhaps only `audit create session whenever not successful` was run. try also running `audit create session whenever successful`, or remove auditing with `noaudit create session` and follow it with an unrestricted `audit create session`.

Comment: Also, you may also want to consider a logon trigger, in which you can capture a lot more enriched info about the session than is exposed in the audit trail, using `v$session`, `v$session_connect_info` and `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV',...)` attributes. Write this to a custom logging table of your own design.

Comment: Is there any way I can check what was run e.g. are the audit settings stored in a parameter table or other table in Oracle?

Comment: DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS, DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS